# FFT algorithm for real-time analysis

Tags: dft, real-time

In a project, I have real-time voice audio being delivered in buffers of around 128 samples at a time. I want to calculate the autocovariance of the signal and use it to control an AR filter.

To do this, I use a Fourier transform and an Inverse Fourier transform.

Edit: Between the forwards and inverse FFT, I am basically just squaring (complex norm) and scaling the signal.

However, with such small buffer sizes I think the frequency resolution will be insufficient. An obvious choice is to fill up a larger, internal buffer and calculate a sliding DFT on the incoming data.

But I was wondering if there are specific algorithms for treating a whole block of incoming data, instead of doing it per individual sample?

Comment: could you expand on what you do between the forwards and reverse dft?

Comment: I am basically just squaring (complex norm) and scaling the result of the forwards FFT. So I suppose that this might be more efficient to do with a convolution in the time-domain (although I don't know if the complex conjugation screws things up?). I have edited the question.

Comment: what is the order of the AR filter?

Comment: It is variable, but will probably run between around 10-30.

Comment: i would think your FFT size would be sufficient. I would suggest some averaging of your autocorrelation over successive frames. im not clear why a longer FFT would help but I don’t really know what is driving your direction

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The averaging between frames is also a good idea, I will keep that in mind.